# How do I make a constraint "5-53" space between views?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

when I want to make a constraint saying that the layout system can have minimum 5 and maximum 53 points between two views, such as

1. ViewA.Leading is greater or equal ViewB.Trailing 5 (pri 1000 multiplier 1)
2. ViewA.Leading is less or equal ViewB.Trailing 53 (pri 1000 multiplier 1)

Interface Builder always gets upset with me, giving me the "Inequality Constraint Ambiguity" error. If this is not the way to make such a constraint, how should it be instead?

(please, I insist on expressing the constraints in a storyboard through Interface Builder)

Cheers

Nik

Comment: What is your intent as far as what space you want between the views? Why are you giving it this range?

Answer (score 2):

The ambiguity is that the auto layout system doesn't know exactly how much space to put. You have successfully placed limits on the range of allowed space, but there are still any number of solutions. For example, 20 points works, but so does 40, and so does 31.2875.

The system needs additional information to pick a specific distance. How much space, specifically, would you prefer if all other constraints allow flexibility?

You could, for example, set a constraint ViewA.Leading equal to ViewB.Trailing plus 20 but at a lower priority. The lower priority would allow it to be overridden by higher priority constraints and things such as content hugging or compression resistance priority. But, all else being equal, the system will try for 20 or as close to 20 as possible. That removes the ambiguity.

But, ultimately, you need to decide how the system should resolve things when there are remaining degrees of freedom and give the system the corresponding constraints to eliminate that freedom, so it can come up with one right answer.